# Can't get sub-folders deployed to Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a .Net Core Worker service where the solution has two sub folders. They don't get published which causes my app to malunction. I can't find the reason for this, see image below. The files in the folders have Build action: "Content" and Coopyt to output directory: Always. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of solution]

Comment: If you run `dotnet publish` and inspect the published folder, do they get published there?

Comment: No they don't. If I build (debug) they are in bin/debug though...